# Cannot find how to reference total of group in Google pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Cannot find how to reference total of group in Google pivot table.
I am trying to get % of groups total (`134.88`/`138.32`)*100 = 97%, i.e.:

[image: part of pivot table]

In Excel there is built in function:

[image: % of Parent Row Total]

In Google Sheets there's only built in function for whole column or whole row. And documentation does not give much help.

Comment: For now did it with index(match()) outside of pivot table. But suggestion how to do it with calculated field and/or with getpivotdata is appreciated.
index match approach:
First tick repeat labels for criteria row
`=IF($B5="","",IFError(D5/(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($B5&" Total",$B:$B,0))),""))`
in match criteria concat row label with & " Total"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is poor but *In Gsheets theres only built in function for whole column or whole row* is incorrect. Assuming your pivot table starts in A1 something like:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("D",A1,"B","01 Project task - translation","C",C2,"A",1)/GETPIVOTDATA("D",A1,"C",C2,"A",1)
```

formatted as Percent will return the percentage you require, provided you apply the correct column labels in place of the substitutes used above (since you neglected to provide any source data) and you substitute the final `1` with whatever is in the cell to the left you have failed to show all of (assuming the pivot table has only a single column to the left).

The catch is that the dates in the source sheet must be Text format.